# Cascading method calls in FitNess?

Tags: java, fitnesse, method-call

I'm new to FIT and FitNess and I'm wondering if is possible to cascade method calls without defining special fixtures.

Background: we are testing our web based GUI with Selenium WebDriver. I have created a framework based on the PageObject pattern to decouple the HTML from the page logic. This framework is used in our JUnit tests. The framework is implemented in a Fluent API style with grammar.

Something like this:

```
boolean connectionTest = 
connectionPage
.databaseHost( "localhost" )
.databaseName( "SOME-NAME" )
.instanceNameConnection()
.instanceName("SOME-INSTANCE-NAME")
.windowsAuthentication()
.apply()
.testConnection();
```

Some testers want to create acceptance tests but aren't developers. So had a look to FIT. Would it be possible to use my framework with FIT as is without developing special fixtures?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can use the existing code with 'plain-vanilla' Fit, it would at least require a special fixture class to be defined. Maybe '[SystemUnderTest](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.FixtureGallery.ImportantConcepts.SystemUnderTest)' could help?

Otherwise [Slim's version](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.SystemUnderTest) might be something to get it to work for you.

As a side note: I've put a [FitNesse baseline installation including features to do website testing with (almost) no Java code](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki) on GitHub. In my experience [it's BrowserTest](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/2.-Slim-Fixtures#browsertest) will allow non-developers to create/modify/maintain tests easily, and integrate those tests with you continuous integration process (if you have one). I would suggest you (or your testers) also have a look at that.

Comment: Thank you for your advise for 'SystemUnderTest'. I had a look at it and it may is not suitable because for some chained method calls it results in objects of a different type (different Page Object). As I have mentioned I would like to avoid writing fixtures because we already have to spent time  in maintaining our framework

Comment: I understand. The point of using my fixtures is that you can use them without writing and maintaining your own...

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked about Java but in case any .NET developers see this, it's possible with the .NET implementation, `fitSharp`:

```
|with|new|connection page|
|with|database host|localhost|
|with|database name|some-name|
```

etc.

See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/WithKeyword.html

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by writing a generic fixture which receives the target methods and their arguments from the fitness table and uses Java reflection to invoke the appropriate framework methods.

So I have one fixture of all different page objects that are returned from the framework.